VSCode extension XSLT/XPath fails to auto tag-close
When using the XSLT/XPATH for Visual Studio Code plugin with VSCode, I have to manually type every closing tag for any XML element.
E.g. if I type
<xsl:t

I correctly get an offer of a matching template resulting in
<xsl:template match="" mode="#default">

</xsl:template>

But when I enter
<any-xml-element>
</

I expect to get am offer of any-xml-element> that I can choose with the TAB or RETURN key.
But that is not the case in my installations on Win10 and Win11.
Currently I am typing the closing tag or cut'n-paste it from the opening one. That is annoying.
It may be a simple configuration or something else that I am missing. The author of that plugin has no solution for me. It works on his computer. Do you have an idea?
Or do you know another free or cheap editor supporting XSLT 3?

With VS code and that extension, can't you type < and then select literal result element block from the auto completion options to get <element>..</element> with element being selected so that you can override it with e.g. any-xml-element and that way you have your start and end tag with the wanted element name?

As for other free or cheep editors supporting XSLT 3, various of Jetbrains IDEs have free versions (I think like "IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition") and there is an XQuery and XSLT plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8612-xquery-and-xslt (for all those Jetbrains IDEs) that supports XSLT 3 with Saxon.

As for "cheap" options, the freelance edition/license of https://www.xmlblueprint.com/buy.htm is 40 USD.

@MartinHonnen, although unusual, your suggestion to start with '' and overtype it works fine. Hence, I will stick to VSCode as we use it for C programming.

However, it does not work in all situations: If I type '<xsl:var' I get '<xsl:variable name="" as="" select=""/>. What is not ok for complex variables that need inner specifiactions. There I have to type </xsl:variable> manually.

It does also not work, if I have the name of the element on the clip board. There I have to substitute both:  and 
A usual auto closing tag, either if I type '>' for the opening tag or if I type '</' would be more convenient.

On the paste issue I have raised https://github.com/DeltaXML/vscode-xslt-tokenizer/issues/142.

The paste issue has been fixed in the latest release of the VS Code xslt 3 extension of today so you can now type e.g. <, select literal-element (block) and override the used element name either by typing or pasting the desired name.

With VS Code and that XSLT 3 extension, for a literal block element of any element name, you can type < and select literal-element (block) in the autocompletion and get e.g.
<element>

</element>

with element being selected and overridable in at the same time in both the start and the end tag.
For a literal inline element you can type < and select literal-element (inline) from the autocompletion and get e.g. <element></element> with element being selected and overridable at the same time in both the start tag and the end tag.

see my notes above

@ngong, your original question was about getting any-xml-element which in my opinion in the context of XSLT is a literal result element to get to work in the environment of VS Code with the XSLT 3 extension. For that I suggested a way. xsl:variable is not a literal result element. And other stuff like copying/pasting not working to your liking are additional features you might want to raise on VS Code editor and/or the extension as an issue, I agree it looks broken if you can override an element by typing at the same type for the start and end tag but not with pasting, raise an issue.

Yes, Martin, your suggested work-around has drawbacks. My original question was about auto-closing an XML element. I am now trying out XMLBlueprint.
